# How and where to install custom fonts in MAMP?

Tags: fonts, mamp, custom-font

Please help a rookie with a simple question:

How and where do I install custom font files in the MAMP admin panel?

I can find nice tutorials of how to do this in c panel, but I can't google the answer to how to do this in the local server. I have no experience in the admin panels since this is the first time around for me. Could anyone provide me with simple advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's still just PHP and Apache, so if you're working with a *pure* MAMP stack and not something on top of that like Wordpress (if you do run something on top of that, *ask about that instead*) the answer is: put them wherever you're serving static content from, like any other static asset.